# Joomla of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, open-source, joomla

If i look into PHP they have Joomla, although it was initially build for CMS only but currently it is doing much more then that, like it have Shopping Card module, blogging, forums and many more. In short for PHP guy they have Joomla as opensource, which just need a little customization and the side is ready within 3days.

Now what we have in ASP.NET, the most famous opensource here is dotNetNuke but don't support web2.0.

My question here is that what do we have in ASP.NET platform or in other word what is Joomla of ASP.NET.

Comment: what do you mean for "doesn't support web 2.0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option is [**DotNetNuke**](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Development/Downloads/CommunityEditionDownload/tabid/1369/Default.aspx), if you want to go for .Net 2.0 then you can choose older version of DNN and you need to search plugins for that DNN.

Another option is [**Umbraco**](http://umbraco.org/download/) CMS. It is also a well known in the community.

There are also third party paid version of CMS which can have functionality that you want.

Comment: DotNetNuke, sorry but i don't like it as it doesn't support web2.0. 

I have also heard about Umbraco. but i don't know its feature list. 
do it have blogging module, forum, shopping cart or its just an cms.

Comment: Orchard CMS as well, although that is ASP.NET MVC